# How to start up dataflow job with Python Code

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow

I want to kick off the dataflow job once i drop one file in the cloud storage.And i start a cloud function to trigger it.But i don't know how to start up the datadlow job with Python?Someone can help?

```
const kickOffDataflow = (input, output) => {
var jobName = CONFIG.DATAFLOW_JOB_NAME;
var templatePath = CONFIG.TEMPLETE_FILE_PATH;
var request = {
    projectId: "test",
    requestBody: {
        jobName: jobName,
        parameters: {
            configFile: input,
            outputFile: output,
            mode: "cluster_test"
        },
        environment: {
            zone: "europe-west1-b"
        }
    },
    gcsPath: templatePath
}
console.log("Start to create " + jobName + " dataflow job");
return google.auth.getClient({
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
}).then(auth => {
    request.auth = auth;
    return dataflow.projects.templates.launch(request);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
});
```

}

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where exactly you don't know how to continue.

Comment: and you can see ,i have code by node.js and  it worked ,but i don't know how to rewritten by python,  my boss need us to change python

Comment: Then you should reword your question to make this clear. Note that requests to program something for you are likely to stay unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Dataflow Cloud Composer Example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/examples/cloud-composer-examples/composer_dataflow_examples). It describes how Cloud Composer can be used in combination with Cloud Functions to trigger a Python based Dataflow job when a new file arrives in a GCS bucket.